# Unable to Knit R Markdown to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

- Tried to knit R markdown file to PDF but this error shows up:

I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log Project_2.log.
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.139 1. S&
P500 Stocks

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Project_2.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Project_2.log for more info.
Execution halted

- Went into the webstie below as suggested by the error but nothing worked.
  https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging

Comment: Well, as the error message is suggesting the issue seems to be that the `&` in `S&P` is interpreted as an alignment character. If you want a literal `&` you have to escape it using e.g. `S\&P`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal  Rmd to reproduce your issue.